# Unable to override in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a peculiar problem where I have to override a particular method present in the **Window** class .

I am using **MVVM** and my ViewModel is inheriting to BaseVm which has **INotifyPropertyChanged**

What I need is this

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
 protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
                base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

                // Hook up handler for window messages
                var windowSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
                if (windowSource == null)
                    return;
                windowSource.AddHook(WiDiOnWindowMessage);

                try
                {
                    _wiDi = new WiDi();
                    _wiDi.ValidateWiDi();

                    //// This is async call so rest of logic handled in OnWiDiWindowMessage
                    //// Pass the window handle which WiDi extensions library uses to send messages back.
                    _wiDi.Initialize((uint)windowSource.Handle.ToInt64());
                }
                catch (WiDiNoWelException)
                {
                    ShowMessageDialog("Warning: The Intel® WiDi auto-connect button is not available.",
                                      "Please use the Intel® WiDi application to connect to your TV.\n" +
                                      "Alternatively you can use an HDMI cable.\n" +
                                      "Issue: The Intel® WiDi Extensions Library (WEL) cannot be found.");
                }
                catch (WiDiNoAppException)
                {
                    ShowMessageDialog("Warning: Intel® WiDi is not available.", 
                                      "Please use an HDMI cable to connect to your TV.\n" +
                                      "Issue: Intel® WiDi cannot be found or this PC may not be Intel® WiDi compatible.");
                }
                catch (WiDiException exception)
                {
                    ShowMessageDialog("Warning: Intel® WiDi is not available.",
                                      "Please use an HDMI cable to connect to your TV.\n" +
                                      "Issue: " + exception.Message);
                }
```

My Current code is

```
public  class HomeWindowVm : BaseVm
    {
     protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
       {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        //    Hook up handler for window messages

         var windowSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
           // var windowsource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        if (windowSource == null)
             return;
         windowSource.AddHook(WiDiOnWindowMessage);

         try
          {
               _wiDi = new WiDi();
              _wiDi.ValidateWiDi();

                // This is async call so rest of logic handled in OnWiDiWindowMessage
                // Pass the window handle which WiDi extensions library uses to send messages back.
                _wiDi.Initialize((uint)windowSource.Handle.ToInt64());
            }
            catch (WiDiNoWelException)
            {
                ShowMessageDialog("Warning: The Intel® WiDi auto-connect button is not available.",
                                  "Please use the Intel® WiDi application to connect to your TV.\n" +
                                  "Alternatively you can use an HDMI cable.\n" +
                                  "Issue: The Intel® WiDi Extensions Library (WEL) cannot be found.");
            }
            catch (WiDiNoAppException)
            {
                ShowMessageDialog("Warning: Intel® WiDi is not available.",
                                  "Please use an HDMI cable to connect to your TV.\n" +
                                  "Issue: Intel® WiDi cannot be found or this PC may not be Intel® WiDi compatible.");
            }
            catch (WiDiException exception)
            {
                ShowMessageDialog("Warning: Intel® WiDi is not available.",
                                  "Please use an HDMI cable to connect to your TV.\n" +
                                  "Issue: " + exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

My problem is that as my Class in Not inheriting fro **Window** .the **OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)** is giving errors > .

how can I inherit from **Window** Class in the same code.

Comment: Are you sure MVVM is the correct pattern for solving this problem?

Comment: my Whole code is in MVVM ! I cant help it out ! I am looking for a way

Comment: Why do you have to override the OnSourceInitialized method? Can't you just add a method of the view model class to the Window's `SourceInitialized` event?

Comment: @Clemens he need windows instance I guess  PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) thats why doing in VM is not possible

Comment: @Nitin The window instance is passed to the `sender` argument of the event handler.

Comment: @Clemen - I am not getting Window class SourceInitialized method

Comment: @Clemens  how can an event handler be added to VM here. It will be added to Windows code behind. If you are talking about interactivity triggers to call command on VM that also does not send UI instance as a param.

Answer (score 2):

Your view model could probably have a `SourceInitialized` method that you attach to the Window's `SourceInitialized` event (instead of overriding the `OnSourceInitialized` method):

```
public class HomeWindowVm : BaseVm
{
    public void SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var window = (Window)sender;
        var windowSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window) as HwndSource;
        ...
    }
}
```

When you create your view model instance, you would attach the handler like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new HomeWindowVm();
    SourceInitialized += vm.SourceInitialized;
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: so you want me to add this code to BaseVM and then Initialize in the HomeWindowVM ?

Comment: @Apoorv I don't want anything, it's just a suggestion. Somewhere you are creating your view model instance, e.g. like shown in the MainWindow constructor in the above code sample. There you would attach the method of the view model class to the SourceInitialized event of your window.

Comment: View references in ViewModel violates the MVVM pattern ;) That's all what MVVM is about (plus DataBinding)

Comment: Hey Clemens..I have a single class file that is HomeWindowVm : BaseVm ...can you tell me where to add that method and where to call it.... ? is this Mainwindow the View file here for the concerened ViewModel ?

Comment: @Clemens have a question ..can you clarify? have asked you above

Comment: @Clemens so the MainWindow() is the view file and View Model is the code for MainWindow () right? one is view and the other is its viewmodel

Comment: @Apoorv Edited the answer to include your view model classes.

Comment: @Apoorv: No, ViewModel is data prepared for a certain view to be consumed plus presentation logic (**not** business logic)

Comment: the code line   base.OnSourceInitialized(e); is giving errors

Comment: @Tseng I am not getting you

Comment: @Apoorv There is no `base.OnSourceInitialized()` to call. Just remove that line.

Comment: @Apoorv: Then you need deeper understanding and studies of MVVM before you continue. It's out of the scope of SO to explain MVVM in full

Comment: @Tseng I know you like discussing this in detail, but here you're just creating confusion. Please be so kind to stop that.

Comment: @Apoorv And sure, `MainWindow()` is the constructor of your MainWindow class, so it's view of course.

Comment: @Clemens ok , I was making it sure..now when I am getting error here     SourceInitialized += vm.SourceInitialized;
 its asking to create a method for SourceInitialized

Comment: @Apoorv Do it like shown in the above code sample. It's working code. If you are creating your view model in a different way, you might add that to your question. It would then be easier to provide a suitable solution for your problem.

Comment: @Clemens lets continue in chat ? would you be able to initiate one? I shall paste my code there and we can have a discussion?

Comment: @Apoorv Sorry, I won't go into any further discussion. As said, you may edit your question with details about how you create your view model instance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in your ViewModel as you can see that `OnSourceInitialized` is a Window function and hence can only be overridden in the derived Window class. It does not make sense to derive VM from Window as VM is intended to provide DataContext to the View (window in your case). Even if you derive VM from Window it would not be the Window that you want to override this function.

So in this case you can either keep this code in your Windows code behind which I don't think is a voilation to MVVM here.

OR you can define a attached behavior and put it on your Window class and check everything in the behavior itself.

Comment: An Attached Behavior can be used, so you don't need to depend on. The behavior can be attached to any window and you wouldn't need to create an inherited control for it. Has the advantage that you don't get issues, when you need this functionality in some other from Window derived class (i.e. `RibbonWindow`), then you can't use your own custom class because C# only allows inheriting from one class. But attached Behavior can be attached to any subclass of i.e. `Window` (or any other type you define, like `UserControl`). This is more "MVVM-esque", since it's decoupled

Comment: thats the biggest problem. C# doesnt allow inheriting from Multiple classes.... I hoped it was Java or C++ ....